# how to split the value in database using explode function in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

i have a column in db which contains set of sentence which is separated by ';' i want to extract the value and print those two statement in two different div's.

For example

```
this is a cow;it gives milk
```

Output should be

```
this is a cow

it gives milk
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `explode` and `foreach` it up

```
<?php
$str='this is a cow;it gives milk';
foreach(explode(';',$str) as $k=>$v)
{
    echo "<div id=div$k>$v</div>";
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
<div id=div0>this is a cow</div>
<div id=div1>it gives milk</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$str='this is a cow;it gives milk';
$arr = explode(';',$str);

<div id="div0"><?php echo $arr[0];?></div>
<div id="div1"><?php echo $arr[1];?></div>
```

or use foreach

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
{
  echo "<div id=div$k>$v</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$dbresult = "this is a cow;it gives milk";
$result=explode(';',$dbresult);
echo $result[0];
echo $result[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
    <?php
    $array = explode(';','this is a cow;it gives milk');
    foreach($array as $key=>$value)
    {
        echo "<div  >".$value."</div>";
    }

?>
```

Output :

```
<div>this is a cow</div>
<div>it gives milk</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
   <?php 
          $value ='this is a cow;it gives milk';
          $split = explode(';',$value);
          for($i=0;$i<count($split);$i++) {
               echo "<div id=div$i>$split[$i]</div>";
          }
     ?>
```

And output will be

```
<div id=div0>this is a cow</div><div id=div1>it gives milk</div>
```

clear reference [see this link.](http://codepad.org/xpUW1yfX)